# MAC OS X lion mac address spoofing problem

Tags: configuration, macintosh, internet, mac-address, spoofing

I have to change the MAC address of my Macbook due to ISP issues. I changed it using:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 ether my_new_mac_address
```

And it is changed successfully when I check it through:

```
ifconfig en1 | grep ether
```

It returns

```
ether my_new_mac_address
```

But when I `ping google`, It can't resolve that, which means it is not connecting to the Internet. Am I missing something?

The IP and gateway was set perfectly.

N.B:The spoofing worked in the same way in Ubuntu, it is connected to internet.

Comment: Try `ping 74.125.234.115`. If it works, then your DNS settings are not okay.